# To upgrade TFS build agent or not to upgrade?

Tags: tfs

I've searched for answers to my question on this forum and elsewhere, but so far unsuccessfully.

We are upgrading our toolset from VS2008/TFS2008 to VS2013/TFS2013. We now have TFS upgraded (phew!) but the big questions remaining are:

1. We have a single build agent using Team Build 2008 running on a Windows 7 x64 SP1 machine, with build results published to an old XP machine. Will the new TFS2013 server be able to work with it fully, or are we compelled to upgrade the build agent to Team Build as well? if so, does Team Build 2013 run on Windows 7 x64 SP1 or will we need a complete new server platform?
2. If we are compelled to upgrade the build agent to Team Build 2013, will/should our existing build scripts continue to work?

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is, "It depends."

The build system was totally redesigned in TFS 2010 to be based on Windows Workflow build process templates instead of MSBuild files. TFS 2010/2012/2013/2015 can all run old-style MSBuild files by using a build process template called "Upgrade Template". Whether they'll work immediately out of the box depends on how customized your MSBuild files are and what (if any) custom assemblies you're using. Custom assemblies may need to be recompiled, or may need code changes to continue to work.

TFS 2008 build agents do not work with TFS 2013. You will need to upgrade your build agents. However, TFS 2013 and 2015 build agents will both [run on Windows 7 SP1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/TFS/administer/requirements), so you're good to go there.

The build system was revamped **again** in TFS 2015. My recommendation would be to get on TFS 2015 ASAP and skip the XAML build system entirely. The new build system is much easier to work with and can be extended with far less pain.

You are in a scenario with a fair amount of risk, especially if your business depends on your CI builds running regularly. Your best bet will be to do a test upgrade of your environment and validate what steps will have to be taken to ensure your builds continue to run against the Upgrade Template, or how much effort it will take to retire your MSBuild-based build templates and switch over to a newer build paradigm.

Regardless, I would strongly recommend making the move to TFS 2015 over 2013. Why go through the effort of upgrading from 2008 to 2013, only to **still** be a major version behind?

Comment: Money. Company can't/won't afford MSDN (for the whole albeit small team it's outrageously expensive over time), and 2013 was the last one-time purchase version we could get.